# Can't create atomic with ()

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, atomic

I was trying to create `std::atomic_bool` objects in different ways:

```cpp
std::atomic_bool f1 = false;   // OK
std::atomic_bool f2 = {false}; // OK
std::atomic_bool f3{false};    // OK
std::atomic_bool f4(false);    // ERROR: expected identifier before «false»
```

Why the last one does not work?

P.S: compile with `g++ -std=c++20`.

EDIT: Those are class member variables.

Comment: cppreference says that constructor `constexpr atomic( T desired ) noexcept` exists.

Comment: I suspect that you forgot to mention that these are member variables. (And didn't care about testing with any other types.)

Comment: You suspect right :) Could you please explain what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize a member variable with parentheses, because that must be a member function declaration according to the grammar.

This syntactic quirk did not cause any issues until it became possible to write member initializers in the variable's declaration.